# Parse.com on Signup User name already exists, code 142

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Update: Solved, happens to be incorrect Cloud Code I wrote, see update #3

I am trying to make a signup for user using Parse.com API in Javascript.
Still with no success.

Basically I have a user field and a password field, and when hit signup button, tries to login but always I have the "**Error Code: 142 :User name already exists, try login** error from Parse api.

What is wrong with the code? (I previously used c# code and it was success)
Thanks in response.

```
function onSignupButtonClicked(button) {
    event.preventDefault();

    game_username = $("#loginUserText").val();
    game_password = $("#loginPasswordText").val();

    parseLogout(); // tried both logout earlier or put here..

    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("username", game_username);
    user.set("password", game_password);


    var progressCircle = showProgressCircle(); //some fullscreen progress

    //also tried user.signup(null, {.. with no luck

    Parse.User.signUp(game_username, game_password, {}, {
        success: function(user) {
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
            //NOW LOGIN

            login(game_username, game_password).then(function(result) {
                console.log(result); // "Stuff worked!"
                hideProgressCircle(progressCircle);

                $("#loginButton").attr("disabled", true);
                $("#logoutButton").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#signupButton").attr("disabled", true);

                game_manualLogin = true;
                isLoggedIn = true;


            }, function(err) {
                hideProgressCircle(progressCircle);

                console.log("loginPromise: " + err.message + " code: " + err.code); // Error: "It broke"
                   handleParseError(err);

            });

        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
                 hideProgressCircle(progressCircle);
               handleParseError(error);

        }
    });

}
```

update:
Even basic Parse.com javascript returns 142.. here is the code, and my location is Istanbul/Turkey

```
function register() {

    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("username", "testop");
    user.set("password", "testop");
    user.set("email", "email@example.com");

    // other fields can be set just like with Parse.Object
    user.set("phone", "415-392-0202");

    user.signUp(null, {
        success: function(user) {
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
            console.log("testop register ok!");

        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });


}
```

This is the error I get to above updated code 
Error:code: 142 :User name already exists, try login (Code is from [Parse Javascript Signup](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-signup)

Update #2:
Even Rest API gives same error:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ gg$ curl -X POST \
>   -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: MYAPPID" \
>   -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: MYRESTAPIKET" \
>   -H "X-Parse-Revocable-Session: 1" \
>   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>   -d '{"username":"testdude","password":"tesdude","phone":"415-392-0202"}' \
>   https://api.parse.com/1/users
{"code":142,"error":"User name already exists, try login"}
MacBook-Pro:~ gg$
```

UPDATE #3:
After checking with 3 apis, found that problem was my fault.
I forgot a Cloud Code on user save, which was faulty as it did not check length of query length..

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
    var username = request.object.get("username");

    var usernamequery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    usernamequery.equalTo("username", username);

    usernamequery.find({
        success: function()
        {
          --->>>should be checking length of query here  <<<---
         console.log("same user name found");
         response.error("User name already exists, try login");
        },
        error: function(error)
        {
         console.log("ok unique user name continue save");
         response.success("OK saving user");
        }   
    });


});
```

Comment: The question contains a phrase "what is wrong with this code" that is an invitation for close votes.  You can improve it by having a theory (or more) about what's wrong, and presenting evidence for/against that theory.  e.g. It sure sounds like the game_username already exists as a user.  Can you present proof that this isn't the case?  As an aside: the code creates a new Parse.User and then ignores it.  You can send signup() to that user instead of using the class method.

Comment: Thank you danh, actual code was user.signup but forgot that when trying. Tom's answer makes sense below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two forms, one for signing up (as a new user) which calls Parse.User.signUp and a second form (for returning users) that calls Parse.User.logIn.

The problem is that you can only 'sign up' once with a username and password, after which you should 'login'. Also when you have got a success callback from Parse.User.signUp then the user is logged in and you don't have to call 'login'.

Something like this (where the two event listeners are triggered by two different buttons).

SIGNUP

```
function onSignupButtonClicked(button) {
    event.preventDefault();

    game_username = $("#loginUserText").val();
    game_password = $("#loginPasswordText").val();

    Parse.User.signUp(game_username, game_password, {}, {
        success: function(user) {
            // A new user has signed up and is now the Parse.User.current() user
            // Do something
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.         
        }
    });

}
```

LOGIN

```
function onLoginButtonClicked(button) {
    event.preventDefault();

    game_username = $("#loginUserText").val();
    game_password = $("#loginPasswordText").val();

    Parse.User.logIn(game_username, game_password, {}, {
        success: function(user) {
            // An existing user has logged in and is now the Parse.User.current() user
            // Do something
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
        }
    });

}
```

More info here: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-signup

Comment: Thank you for response but I think something wrong with parse... even base signup code that is on parse website, returns 142...

Comment: Thank you.. Actual problem was me forgotting there was a cloudcode on parse side... I forgot a Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User..) function on parse code.. 142 is validation error and text response is actually my response!.